# What lens filter size should I get?

Tags: lens, filters, compatibility

I ordered a 65mm lens filter, and my camera has a 58mm lens. Would the filter fit because I ordered it online and I'm not sure if it will work with my camera?

Comment: For what? you would need to give more information if you want a useful answer along with information on budget and so on. - try Lenshero.com

Comment: a 65mm thread will not fit on a 58mm thread - only a 58mm thread will. if you still want/need the 65mm filter, go for a step-up adapter.

Comment: Hey amr - welcome to Photo.SE. Please provide us some detail to better answer your question. What camera system (Nikon, Canon, Pentax, Fuji, etc.)? What lens are you buying a filter for? Do you have other lenses that the filter should also work for?

Comment: Wait, is the **focal length** of the lens 58mm, or is the lens's **filter thread diameter** 58mm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the right size of filters for a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/how-do-i-find-the-right-size-of-filters-for-a-lens)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have a lens with a 58mm filter thread, and you have ordered a 65mm lens filter.  You will need a 58-65mm [step-up ring/adapter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/what-is-the-difference-between-a-step-up-and-a-step-down-ring) in order to make this work.  If you can find one, it would have 58mm threads that screw into your lens, and 65mm threads that the filter can then screw into.